# How to set size of JList with Scrollbar in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jscrollbar

How to set scrollbar in JList and how to set the size of JList. I have a jList and in JList I want to set fix height. If I have data more then that height I want to show a scrollbar.

Comment: Wrap it in JscrollPane

Comment: Beware, using `setPreferredSize` on a `JList` will prevent the `JList` from changing size in relationship to it's model.  You should be using `setVisibleRowCount` and/or `setPrototypeCellValue` in order to provide hints about it's size and viewport preferred sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a JLit in scrollbar

```
JList<Object> list =  new JList<Object>();
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
```

To size the JList

```
list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
```

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). The problem with this is it's going to restrict both the width and height of the `JList` and prevent it from changing size in relationship to it's model

Answer (score 2):

> how to set scrollbar in JList

Wrap the `JList` to a `JScrollPane`

```
JList list = ...;
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
// Add the scrollpane to the container
```

See [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

> and how to set size of JList.

You can use [`JList#setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount(int)) to affect the the number of visible rows the `JList` would like to show when wrapped in a `JList`.

You can also use [`JList#setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue(E)) which is the "default" value the `JList` will use to calculate the size of individual cells, this is intended as a performance enhancement, but will effect the width of the `JList`